# What does "25 of them" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it refer to **thousands of situations** in the previous sentence?

"Dreyer's hospital is enthusiastically embracing the potential of AI to transform radiology. They've bulked up their computing power and are organizing their data to train algorithms. But there's a long road ahead. Artificial intelligence will need to be able to respond to **thousands of situations** to match the image interpretation that a radiologist does. Right now, Massachusetts General Hospital is focusing on **25 of them**."

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2017/07/14/technology/business/radiology-doctors-artificial-intelligence/index.html

Comment: Yes, the referent of _them_ is _thousands of situations_. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that **"25 of them"** refers to "**25 situations**"

It can be verified from this [link](https://science.slashdot.org/story/17/07/15/1738207/can-ai-replace-hospital-radiologists/), which states that Massachusetts General Hospital is focusing on training their Artificial Intelligence to respond to 25 common situations encountered at the radiology department.

But I had to google a specific set of keywords to arrive at this answer, because the sentence to me is ambiguous on whether the article was referring to 25 AIs or 25 situations because an AI(or neural network) generally is 'trained' based on the data of thousands of images in order to make it 'understand' how to respond whenever it sees a new image.

It's all pattern matching, really.

Comment: I don't think it's too ambiguous. To go from AI as a mass noun to "25 of them" seems quite a leap.

Comment: It is ambiguous to me, a non-native English speaker and hence, I write. Might I also point out that the sentence you refer begins as, "Artificial intelligence will need to ..." and I view it as a collective noun(a.k.a mass noun) too, but I perceive the context as providing a description of the capabilities of a set, and then stating that 25 members of that set are located somewhere or being utilized for some purpose.

Comment: But thank you for that perspective. @LukeSawczak

Comment: Where is the answer?

Comment: @P.E.Dant : Thank you for seeking clarification. You can now find it in the first line.

Comment: I'm baffled. If a student of English should find this answer upon searching our site, what will the student gain from learning that you _"had to google a specific set of keywords to arrive at this answer, because the sentence to me is ambiguous on whether the article was referring to 25 AIs or 25 situations because an AI(or neural network) generally is 'trained' based on the data of thousands of images in order to make it 'understand' how to respond whenever it sees a new image"_? How does this explain why the referent of _they_ is _situations_? What has the google search engine to do with it?

Comment: @P.E.Dant : I'm baffled at your response. The question asks for whether the reference was to the thousands of situations, and I responded that it referred to 25 among the thousands. Done. I was not clear on why exactly, which is why  I'm trying to imply that it's not easy to infer what the meaning was and that I too was lost and resorted to googling to **get some context**. If you have the correct explanation that could be reasonably explained to a **student of English**, please post an answer of your own.

Comment: My comment must have been unclear. My question was: _"**what will the student gain** from learning that you 'had to google a specific set of keywords...(etc.)_"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62373/discussion-between-george-and-p-e-dant).

Comment: Hopefully, one would learn that English is a tricky language.

Answer (score 0):

You ask about *25 of them*. The pronoun *them* refers to something plural, that is, a plural referent.

The natural plural referent of *them* is *thousands of situations*. Thus *25 of them* refers to *25 of thousands of situations*.

It's like when my mom threw away hundreds of my Barbie dolls. I rescued  *12 of them*; that is I rescued  *12 of hundreds of my Barbie dolls* that my mom threw away.